# Azure attach data disk via python API

Tags: python, azure

Does anyone have the solution of attaching data disks to a VM through python ARM version 1.0.2 API?

I've tried adding the metadata to the disk, but it doesn't seem work.

```
'disk5.vhd': { 'metadata': { 'x-ms-meta-microsoftazurecompute_diskid': '9bab45ae-b69c-47d6-952e-9b4320884f01',
                                 'x-ms-meta-microsoftazurecompute_diskname': 'disk5',
                                 'x-ms-meta-microsoftazurecompute_disksizeingb': '22',
                                 'x-ms-meta-microsoftazurecompute_disktype': 'DataDisk',
                                 'x-ms-meta-microsoftazurecompute_resourcegroupname': 'pythonvm10085',
                                 'x-ms-meta-microsoftazurecompute_vmname': 'pythonvm10085'},
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can leverage python sdk for service management to add a data disk to a VM. Please refer to [add_data_disk()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicemanagement-legacy/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementservice.py#L2247) on GitHub repro.

To implement this in python project, we need to create a certificate first. To do this, download your [publish settings](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301775), then use this code named `ManagementCertificate` in this file to create the .pem file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
from azure.servicemanagement import get_certificate_from_publish_settings
from azure.servicemanagement import ServiceManagementService

cert_file = 'myCert.pem'
subscription_id = get_certificate_from_publish_settings(
    publish_settings_path=’publish file path’,
    path_to_write_certificate='myCert.pem',
)
#print subscription_id
sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, cert_file)

service_name = 'myservicename' #cloud service name contained the VM
deployment_name = 'myservicename'
role_name = 'myservicename'
lun = 0

result = sms.add_data_disk(service_name,deployment_name,role_name,lun,media_link='http://{example}.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/testdisk.vhd',logical_disk_size_in_gb=1)
sms.wait_for_operation_status(result.request_id, timeout=600)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the servicemanagement only supports the azure classic portal. I am looking for the Resource menagement python SDK which supports the new azure preview portal.

Comment: To leverage ARM, you can refer to http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagementcomputenetwork.html#create-virtual-machine, where there is a function `compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update()` in this example

Comment: And you can find datadisk class parameters at http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.html?highlight=datadisk#azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.DataDisk